# Vibration of point load on a halfspace

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, closed-form-expressions

The amplitude of vibration of surface of halfspace at a distance r from a point harmonic load of amplitude Q is given by

$ w(r,0) = $
$ Q\over 2\pi G $
$    \int_0^\infty $
$ k^{2}\alpha pJ_0(pr)dp \over((2p^{2}-k^{2})^{2}- 4\alpha\beta p^{2})$

$     \alpha =  \sqrt{p^{2}-(\eta k)^{2}} $

$ \beta =   \sqrt{p^{2}-k^{2}} $

$  k = \omega/V_{s} $

Can this integral be obtained in closed form?  The integral is a function of r, k and $\eta$ .

Comment: In your expression for the integral, why is the $dp$ in the middle?

Comment: There is really no point in asking this kind of question without reporting what Wolfram Alpha/Sage/Mathematica/Maple tells you about it.

Comment: @YemonChoi, probably it is a literal conversion to inline form of an integral that might be written as $$\int_0^\infty \frac{k^2\alpha p J_0(p r)\textrm dp}{((2p^2 - k^2)^2 - 4\alpha\beta p^2)^2}.$$  (Of course, one might argue that even that integral should have the $\textrm dp$ alongside, rather than in the numerator.)

Comment: @YemonChoi has expressed the integral properly in its native form.  Can any one answer this question?

Comment: please, The denominator should not be squared.